# How to identify whether code runs under ASP.Net or regular AppDomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, appdomain

I have some infrastructure code that can run under regular `AppDomain` and in some other case under the ASP.Net `AppDomain`.

The behavior of the code should be different for these two cases.

How can I identify under which type of `AppDomain` I am running **without depending on the `System.Web` namespace** assemblies since this is infrastructure code?

For example:

```
public static string BasePath
{
    get
    {
        var isAspNetAppDomain = ...
        return isAspNetAppDomain 
            ? Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin") 
            : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check also linked questions in comments.

Comment: @Andrey The linked answer requires taking a dependency on `System.Web` which I can't do. I've edited the question to reflect this constraint.

Comment: That answer was criticized for not being reliable anyway, this one is much better and no dependencies: `(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData(".appDomain") != null)`

Comment: Anyway the best way is to pass this information via constructor from highest level. Like `new YourClass(Env.AspNet)`. Calling code always knows.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this sort of thing is a bad design. If the behavior is different in the two cases, then it's  really either two separate methods, or one method with a bool parameter:

```
public static string GetBasePath(bool isAspNetAppDomain)
{
        return isAspNetAppDomain 
            ? Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin") 
            : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
}
```

Comment: The question is about how to figure out what's `isAspNetAppDomain`...